# sum of a column : Pandas .sum() returns 0.0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, sum

I am trying to sum values of columns from a dataframe using `.sum()` with pandas. However, pandas returns '0.00' for all columns that have a datatype of 'float64'. It seems to be working fine for columns set as integers.

here is what I have tried so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, delimiter=';')
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0) *#I want to convert values to numeric*
print(df['UE'].dtype) *#I print dtype of a column I am interested in to check if pandas converted as requested*
print(df.sum(skipna=True))
```

The line `df.sum(skipna=True))` returns 0.00 for every columns set as float64.
For column 'version dossier', it returns the correct sum which is 271.0. (See joined photo).

Here is what the console gives me:

[Console results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDDiQ.png)

Does anyone has an idea why this is hapenning?

Comment: Copy and paste your csv data (or the first 10 lines of it) as code so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: I suggest you look at the output of your data after: `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').`. My guess is everything is coerced to NaN because the format is incorrect to be interpreted as a number.  Given the non-english column names could be something as simple as a `','` being used as a thousands separator or decimal indicator, so add `thousands=','` or `decimal=','` to the `read_csv`

Comment: @ALollz I tried adding decimal=',' to the read_csv as you suggested and it worked just fine. Turns out the problem was what you guessed. It is indeed a french file and my csv was using this format  of number : '8000000,00'. Pandas could not read it without the argument decimal=','. Thank you so much for your help ! I was a bit lost.

Comment: @pakpe Thanks for your time. Here is a sample of the csv (column 'UE' that did not work) : `UE
800000,00
17324000,00
149850,00
50000,00
800000,00
309739,00
55000,00
500000,00
131186,65`It turns out it is the use of comas that was the problem. By adding `decimal=','` to `read_csv` as ALollz suggested, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I post the answer that worked for me for future users. @Alollz found the solution.

@ALollz suggested :
"I suggest you look at the output of your data after: df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').. My guess is everything is coerced to NaN because the format is incorrect to be interpreted as a number. Given the non-english column names could be something as simple as a ',' being used as a thousands separator or decimal indicator, so add thousands=',' or decimal=',' to the read_csv"

It turns out numbers from my csv_file were in a format that could not be interpreted as float by pandas as it contained comas (exemple of format used : '8 000 000,00'. By adding `decimal=','` to the `read_csv`, pandas was able to get interpret my numbers as floats and not NaN.

Here is the updated code :

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, delimiter=';', decimal=',')
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
print(df['UE'].dtype)
```

When I run this, pandas gives me the correct answer.